# Getting info from command-line parameter in Java

Tags: java, command-line

Hello all I'm currently working on a UDP send/receive program but I'm just kind of confused on how to get information from command-line parameter. I know you're supposed to use args but my program is going to have two different inputs. Inputs would be something like (192.168.0.0, 68).  I was just confused how to put that into Java code.

Comment: [Command-Line Arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) - Command line arguments are no different from any other parameter passed to any other method

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling your class from the command line:

```
java MyClass 192.168.0.0 68
```

and then inside your class, your `main()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  String firstArg = args[0];  // 192.168.0.0
  String secondArg = args[1]; // 68
  // use these parameters as needed.
  ...
}
```